# Django-filter BooleanFilter with rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I would like to set a field by using BooleanFilter that filters where quantity_remaining > 0.

This is what I have written down so far:

```
in_stock = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name="quantity_remaining",lookup_expr="gt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NumberFilter` And set `lookup_expr` as gt like this.

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import BaseInFilter, NumberFilter
import django_filters.rest_framework
import django_filters.filters

class NumberInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class FilterClass(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    in_stock = NumberInFilter(field_name="quantity_remaining", lookup_expr="gt")

class StockClass(ListAPIView):
    filterset_class = FilterClass
```